# How to know if date passed with moment.js, considering only date

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, momentjs

i want to know if date passed, only considering date, actualy i have `!moment(moment().format("LLL")).isBefore(moment.unix(data.dueDate._seconds).format("LLL"))`
but it cosider the time too, so if today is 25/jun 6am and is comparing with 25/jun 10pm, it is going to be detected as passed date. I want to consider only the date, not the time. So if today is 25/jun and it is comparing to another date of 25/jun, it should not be a passed date. Is this posible with moment.js?

Comment: did you try moment(moment().format("YYYYMMDD")).isBefore(moment.unix(data.dueDate._seconds).format("YYYYMMDD"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solve, my solution was this: `moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD") > moment.unix(data.dueDate._seconds).format("YYYY-MM-DD")`

Answer (score 0):

moment(moment().format("YYYYMMDD")).isBefore(moment.unix(data.dueDate._seconds).format("YYYYMMDD"))